# How to use condition in form view of Odoo 9?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to do something like this:-

```xml
<record id="view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">module.form</field>
    <field name="model">module.form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="another_module.view_form"/>
    <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook" position="replace">
            <notebook t-if="context.get('no_error', False)">
                <page name="A" string="A">
                    <group>
                        <field name='save'/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
            <notebook t-if="not context.get('no_error', False)">
                <page name="A" string="A">
                    <group>
                        <field name='save' widget="my_widget"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

But I am getting both notebook in the UI/View

I tried to print the value using t-esc but but I am not getting any value.

Is it possible to do something like this or can we use context in xpath ?

Comment: You cannot use qweb on normal forms. That's for templates and reports

Comment: @ChesuCR Is there other way to apply condition somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use qweb on normal form views. That's for templates and reports

### Approach 0

But you can create an auxiliar field, it might be a computed field for example

```py
aux = fields.Char(
    string='Aux',
    compute='_compute_sale_order'
)

@api.multi
@api.depends('some_field')
def _compute_aux(self):
    self.aux = 'no_error'
    # or self.env.context.get('no_error', False)
```

The XML view should be then:

```xml
<record id="view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">module.form</field>
    <field name="model">module.form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="another_module.view_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="before"> <!-- or some other field -->
            <field name="aux" invisible="1" />
        </field>

        <notebook position="inside">
            <page name="A" string="A" attrs="{'invisible': [('aux', '=', 'no_error')]}">
                <group>
                    <field name="save" widget="my_widget"/>
                </group>
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </field>
</record>
```

Keep in mind that you can´t use the the same item twice in the same form. So if you want to show `<field name='save'/>` or `<field name='save' widget="my_widget"/>` you should create an independent form view for each one.

### Approach 1

Or you can try modifying the view with the method `fields_view_get` that should be defined in your model, something like this (I didn´t test it yet):

```py
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form',
                    context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(ModelName, self).fields_view_get(
        cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context,
        toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        eview = etree.fromstring(res['arch'])
        no_error = context.get('no_error', False)

        if eview.attrib.get('name', '') == 'save' and no_error != False:
            eview.set('widget','my_widget')

        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(eview)
    return res
```

Comment: Can we create a view (say new_view) from an existing view (say old_view) using inheritance but old_view will not change .